# AWS DMS with opensearch as target issue with DML update

Tags: aws-dms, amazon-opensearch

I've starting using AWS DMS with oracle as source and Opensearch as target of data.
Replication is setup for full load + continuos replication

Everything is being sync correctly with inserts and deletes from oracle to opensearch.
The problem is when I update a field in oracle and what happens in opensearch

Table in oracle has the following DDL
 `CREATE TABLE "Z_TEST_DMS"  (     "ID_TEST" NUMBER(*,0),  "NAME_TEST" VARCHAR2(200),  "DESC_TEST" VARCHAR2(200),  "NUM_TEST" NUMBER(*,0),  CONSTRAINT "Z_TEST_DMS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_TEST") ) ;`

When I do the following command

`update Z_TEST_DMS set name_test = 'NAME3' where ID_TEST in (2)`

When I do this in oracle, after a couple seconds records with ID_TEST = 2 are updated in opensearch BUT all columns becomes NULL except name_test that is correctly updated and the table key (ID_TEST)

I've tried to find for dms task configurations with some relation with this but I've got no success.

The expected is that all column values remains the same except name_test column which I was updating

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just Find out the solution after enabling supplemental log on oracle, i had to alter table as

> alter table GTP.Z_TEST_DMS ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (all) columns